# HTML/CSS feature detection for PWA

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser, progressive-web-apps

MDN defines '*progressive*' in progressive web apps as -

> Modern web apps can be developed to provide a super cool experience to
>   fully capable browsers, and an acceptable (although not quite as
>   shiny) experience to less capable browsers. We've been doing this for
>   years with best practices such as progressive enhancement, so let's
>   keep up the good work.

I understand that in terms of javascript features, we can use *if-else* conditions to check for existence of feature and handle it appropriately.

But what are best ways to do this for HTML/CSS ?

The google / MDN documentation lay strong emphasis on checking for JS features, but have no documentation for html/css.

My use case is to build a web app that has modern features, but still works on all kinds of browsers (including proxy browsers like Opera Mini and UC Browser).

Comment: Which feature do you want to detect? Most features can be detected with [Modernizer](https://modernizr.com/download?setclasses). Without explaining which feature you want to detect, this question is not answerable and will likely be closed.

Comment: @styfle  Its not about individual features, but what are the best practices in this regard.

Answer (score 5):

By using a script library called [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) you can add checks for different HTML5/CSS3 features into your pages with a minimal amount of code,

To generate a production script, the site provides a custom script generation tool rather than providing a single script that has everything for HTML5/CSS3 feature detection. Using the script generation tool you can pick the specific test functionality that you need and ignore everything that you don’t need.

[Here](http://html5doctor.com/using-modernizr-to-detect-html5-features-and-provide-fallbacks/) is great article on how to use Modernizr

[image]

If you want to go beyond modernizr, you can start using new CSS rule @supports for feature detection. This rule is part of the [CSS3 Conditional Rules Module](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/#at-supports). Thanks to this rule, you can selectively apply CSS styles only when browser supports them. Otherwise, the browser will ignore these styles. It’s syntax is very similar to CSS media queries.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to check the availability of CSS features for expample backdrop-filter within Javascript you can use:

```
CSS.supports("backdrop-filter", "blur(10px)")
```

In a condition:

```
if (CSS.supports("backdrop-filter", "blur(10px)")) {
     // some code when supported
} else {
     // some code when not supported
}
```

This works not for Internet Explorer so if there is a fallback it's better.